# Firefox updated preferences & addons without asking?

Tags: firefox

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Firefox 46.0.1.

FF (Firefox) was completely closed. Then I opened it and suddenly:

- Several (about 5) tabs were automatically opened which were related to my addons.
- The configurations for NoScript addon **were reset**.
- The help pages of Firefox/Mozilla website were aligned RTL (my language is also RTL), though I'm used to read it LTR (English).
- Also, the **default homepage of FF was changed** to firefox' default homepage (usually happens only after installation - which is a "google site" with firefox theme )

On the one hand it seems normal I guess.. On the other hand I'm not used to this behavior.
How do I tell whether this is legit? (it happened about half an hour ago)

Ubuntu didn't update anything since 2 June.

Answer (score -1):

Those multiple tabs are the Firefox add-ons telling you they've updated themselves, and you can disable that behavior in Firefox.  On the menu bar at the top of the Ubuntu screen, go to Tools -> Addons, click on Extensions, then use the Options or Preferences button for each add-on you have installed.

The changed home page is Firefox updating itself.  You can reset that to what you want under Edit -> Preferences.  (It annoys me that this isn't under Tools -> Options as it is in Windows Firefox, but that's a Firefox issue, not an Ubuntu issue.)

Comment: It never happened to me that firefox changed its homepage after an upgrade. Why NoScript configurations (Block & Allow sites lists) were reset?